# How to extract JSON values and run a for loop with curl for each one?

Tags: php, json, bash, curl

I have a json like this

```
{
"results": [{
    "id": 50672,
    "adult": false
}, {
    "id": 281298,
    "adult": false
}, {
    "id": 567604,
    "adult": false
}],
"page": 1,
"total_pages": 1,
"total_results": 1
}
```

and want to extract the id values and run a curl for each one of the values in a for loop probably something like

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"
  do
    curl -O "https://localhost/$i"
  done
```

in php...or bash it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you could simply:

```
foreach(json_decode($json)->results as $result) {
    $content = file_get_contents("https://localhost/script.php?id=" . $result->id);
    // do something with $content e.g. file_put_contents("filename", $content);
}
```